# In wtforms How to use the example from the docs in a real form?

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

In the [wtform docuentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/wtforms/2.1/wtforms.pdf) the following function is described as a widget that can render a SelectMultipleField as a collection of checkboxes:

```
def select_multi_checkbox(field, ul_class='', **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('type', 'checkbox')
    field_id = kwargs.pop('id', field.id)
    html = [u'<ul %s>' % html_params(id=field_id, class_=ul_class)]
    for value, label, checked in field.iter_choices():
        choice_id = u'%s-%s' % (field_id, value)
        options = dict(kwargs, name=field.name, value=value, id=choice_id)
        if checked:
            options['checked'] = 'checked'
        html.append(u'<li><input %s /> ' % html_params(**options))
        html.append(u'<label for="%s">%s</label></li>' % (field_id, label))
    html.append(u'</ul>')
    return u''.join(html)
```

I am trying to actually use this as an example to see what it looks like in one of my forms. However I am having some trouble and I am not sure how to call it since I am only used to using the default fields. This is what I have tried:

```
class myForm(FlaskForm):
    my_choices = [('1', 'Choice1'), ('2', 'Choice2'), ('3', 'Choice3')]
    my_multi_select = SelectMultipleField(choices = my_choices,id='Test')
    my_checkbox_multi_select = select_multi_checkbox(my_multi_select)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
line 52, in select_multi_checkbox
field_id = kwargs.pop('id', field.id)
AttributeError: 'UnboundField' object has no attribute 'id'
```

My next iteration was this:

```
my_checkbox_multi_select = select_multi_checkbox(SelectMultipleField,ul_class='',choices=my_choices,id='test')
```

This also gave me an error with the id attribute but the field wasn't Unbounded anymore.

```
line 52, in select_multi_checkbox
field_id = kwargs.pop('id', field.id)
AttributeError: type object 'SelectMultipleField' has no attribute 'id'
```

I was wondering what the proper way to implement this is. I see that it is a function so I thought that it needed to be called on a field but I wasn't sure what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured this out. I guess it was in the documentation but it was unclear to me for a while. Here is what I did to render this field. I guess this should have been obvious but if anyone else is looking for this here it is:

```
tester = SelectMultipleField(choices=my_choices, widget=select_multi_checkbox)
```

Just call it as a widget. Simple enough. I wish I had put that together earlier.